# How to send a message notification based on a flagged node being linked via entity reference?

Tags: 7, rules, flags, message-subscribe

I'm trying to figure out how to make the following work: Sending notification based on flagged node being linked via entity reference.

I have a **'News'** content type and a **'Band'** content type, that has a flag called 'fan'. When somebody becomes a fan, I want them to receive a notification via the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module whenever I link the band to the content type 'News' with the News article I just created.

The content-type setup is as follows:

- Node type 'News' has field:
  *Entity reference* to content type 'Band'
- The Band content type has a *flag called 'fan'*
- The Message type is called "**user notification center**" and has a field named *field_mnc_recipients*, which is an reference to a user(unlimited values)

How I want it to work:

- when a user flags the 'band' and a new article is referenced to the band, I want to notify them with the Message module,
- to make it work, I need to get the user from the flag for that band and insert it into the message field  *field_mnc_recipients*.

I created a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Component as follows:

```
{ "rules_message_tes3" : {
"LABEL" : "message tes3",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"USES VARIABLES" : {
  "referencing_node" : { "label" : "referencing_node", "type" : "node" },
  "referenced_node" : { "label" : "referenced_node", "type" : "message" }
},
"IF" : [
  { "node_is_of_type" : {
      "node" : [ "referencing-node" ],
      "type" : { "value" : { "bands" : "bands" } }
    }
  },
  { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "referenced-node" ], "type" : "message" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "referenced-node" ], "field" : "field_mnc_recipients" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "referencing-node:flag-fan-user" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "data_set" : {
            "data" : [ "referenced-node:field-mnc-recipients" ],
            "value" : [ "referencing-node:flag-fan-user" ]
          }
        },
        { "entity_create" : {
            "USING" : {
              "type" : "message",
              "param_type" : "user_notification_center",
              "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
            },
            "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

And now I got stuck, I based the component on "[Sending a message to users of a flagged node when it is referenced](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115434)" which is close to what I want.

Comment: great question, too bad I don't have time to tackle this one, but seems doable.

Comment: @NoSssweat still no time? I'm curious about what you were thinking "back then" ...

Answer (score 0):

It works, after days and days it finaly works! I used this as a base line for my research: [Sending a message to users of a flagged node when it is referenced](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115434/sending-a-message-to-users-of-a-flagged-node-when-it-is-referenced)

Instead of sending an e-mail within the loop, i create a new entity(action), in this case the message notification. After that i fill(set data) in the entity-created:field-mnc-recipients field with the flagging users. This is how it works :)

Comment: Please add an export of your rule in this answer to elaborate on how exactly you did this. And consider marking your own answer as "accepted" also (so that the question no longer appears as "unanswered" ...).